# How to avoid over lapping bubbles in bubble plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, bubble-chart

I want to separately plot data in a bubble plot like the image right (I make this in PowerPoint just to visualize).
[image]
At the moment I can only create a plot that looks like in the left where the bubble are overlapping. How can I do this in R?

```
b <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = Type))

b + geom_point(aes(color = Spp, size = value), alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#0000FF", "#DAA520",  "#228B22","#E7B888")) +
  scale_size(range = c(0.5, 12))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have the use of `position_dodge()` argument in your `geom_point`. If you apply it directly on your code, it will position points in an horizontal manner, so the idea is to switch your x and y variables and use `coord_flip` to get it in the right way:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(y = as.factor(Year), x = Type))+ 
  geom_point(aes(color = Group, size = Value), alpha = 0.6, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#0000FF", "#DAA520",  "#228B22","#E7B888")) +
  scale_size(range = c(1, 15)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Does it look what you are trying to achieve ?

---

**EDIT: Adding text in the middle of each points**

To add labeling into each point, you can use `geom_text` and set the same `position_dodge2` argument than for `geom_point`.

NB: I use `position_dodge2` instead of `position_dodge` and slightly change values of width because I found `position_dodge2` more adapted to this case.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(y = as.factor(Year), x = Type))+ 
  geom_point(aes(color = Group, size = Value), alpha = 0.6, 
             position = position_dodge2(width  = 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#0000FF", "#DAA520",  "#228B22","#E7B888")) +
  scale_size(range = c(3, 15)) +
  coord_flip()+
  geom_text(aes(label = Value, group = Group), 
            position = position_dodge2(width = 1))
```

[image]

**Reproducible example**

As you did not provide a reproducible example, I made one that is maybe not fully representative of your original dataset. If my answer is not working for you, you should consider providing a reproducible example (see here: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))

```r
Group <- c(LETTERS[1:3],"A",LETTERS[1:2],LETTERS[1:3])
Year <- c(rep(1918,4),rep(2018,5))
Type <- c(rep("PP",3),"QQ","PP","PP","QQ","QQ","QQ")
Value <- sample(1:50,9)
df <- data.frame(Group, Year, Value, Type)
df$Type <- factor(df$Type, levels = c("PP","QQ"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @dc37 I really appreciate your prompt reply

Comment: Hi @dc37, Just a quick favor, how could I denote each value on the top of its' bubble? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What to do you mean ? Adding the value number of each number on top of each bubble ? or in the middle of each bubbles ?

Comment: Yes, in the middle of each bubble how to label it’s value.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to do that. Let me know if it is working

Comment: Wow, great. Thanks a heap @dc37 . This is exactly what I want. Struggled whole day to do this :) it’s a very big df and everything was going jammed. Thank you again. Have a great weekend 